# Browser autocomplete suuport in flex (email field)?

Tags: apache-flex, email, browser, autocomplete

Does Flex support browser's autocomplete?

I would like it to suggest my users their used emails for an email field,
as done in html (input type="email" autocomplete="on").

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can read the browsers autocomplete list, but you could implement your own autocomplete component in Flex, give http://hillelcoren.com/flex-autocomplete/ a try!

Comment: having an autocomplete is only the front-end. The question focuses on weather the user's used emails can be fetched?

Comment: Yes, and the answer to that is no, while the solution would be implementing your own autocomplete component and storing this in your own application.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying; although that would be limited to emails used only within my own application context, and it wouldn't help if this is the user's 1st time visit (e.g. providing email list in registration page).

Answer (score 0):

> Does Flex support browser's autocomplete?

You will not be able to access any browser specific data inside of a Flex app.  Flex does not have an AutoComplete component built in; but there are a few out there.

I prefer ours for obvious reasons; so I suggest checking out the [Flextras AutoCompleteComboBox](https://www.flextras.com/index.cfm?event=ProductHome&productID=19) component, which has an MX Version, a Spark version, works on mobile and is available for free for production use.